# Empty set while selecting data in MySQL relational database

Tags: database, mysql, relational-database

I have some relational MySQL database with dozens of tables... My query is 1000 ft long and selects data from almost all the tables... I also have my 'main' table, and all other tables are referring to that one. When I enter one row in my main table and when I create all relations for that row in other tables my query works fine. However, if I enter one row in main table and nowhere else I get empty set. But I would like to get at least that information in my result. Or, of course, all information that is entered in other tables, regardless of the fact that some tables don't have information for that record (row)...

Thanks for help!

**Update:**

I don't use JOIN syntax and my query looks similar to this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.*, f.*";
$query .= " FROM a, b, c, d, e, f";
$query .= " WHERE a.aID = b.aID";
$query .= " AND b.bID = c.bID";
$query .= " AND b.bID = d.bID";
$query .= " AND b.bID = e.bID";
$query .= " AND b.bID = f.bID";
```

Comment: Can we see the query? Your question is pretty abstract.

Comment: Your question as it is now is unanswerable. Please post your schema, the query and some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very vague for now, but most probably it is due to the fact you use `INNER JOIN`s instead of the `LEFT JOIN`s.

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    main
JOIN    secondary
ON      secondary.main_id = main.id
```

will return nothing if `secondary` is empty.

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    main
LEFT JOIN
        secondary
ON      secondary.main_id = main.id
```

will return *at least* one record for each record in `main`, replacing secondary fields with `NULL`s if there are no matching records in `secondary`.

**Update:**

Implicit `JOIN` syntax you use (enumerating the tables and providing the `JOIN` conditions in the `WHERE` clause) assumes `INNER JOIN`s.

Assuming that `a` is the "main" table, rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.*, f.*
FROM    a
LEFT JOIN
        b
ON      b.aID = a.aID
LEFT JOIN
        с
ON      c.bID = b.bID
LEFT JOIN
        d
ON      d.bID = b.bID
LEFT JOIN
        e
ON      e.bID = b.bID
LEFT JOIN
        f
ON      f.bID = b.bID
```

Comment: This works as expected... I thought that there is no difference between your and mine queries, but obviously this is what I was looking for! Thank you very much for help...